# Strange algorithm to convert binary SHA-1 digest to hex string

Tags: java, integer, hex, sha1

in the Internet I found this code to generate a SHA1 hash:

```
        public static String hash(String str) {
            try {
                    MessageDigest mg = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                    byte[] result = mg.digest(str.getBytes());
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                            sb.append(Integer.toString((result[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
                    }
                    return sb.toString();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    System.err.println("SHA-1 not found.");
                    return "";
            }
    }
```

But why is there `(result[i] & 0xff) + 0x100`?

Comment: Please read faq before posting.

Comment: @Nikhil: What's wrong with this post?

Comment: @pino copying code and asking here. Can't he refer official documents first. and show hhat he studied.is efforts t

Comment: @Nikhil: I don't agree.  What official document could answer his question?  Copying someone else's code is not discouraged by the FAQ, on the contrary FAQ says "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them". He has a problem with a software algorithm he cannot understand: it's perfectly in-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bytes are signed: they could be negative.  When a negative byte is handled by `Integer.toString()` generates a string beginning with "FFFFFF", but this doesn't happen with positive bytes, so the length of the resulting string is not fixed.  The `& 0xff` converts the byte to an unsigned integer.  Then 0x100 is added to ensure that the hex string is 3 chars long; this is needed because we want a string with 2 hex digits for each byte but a byte between 0 and 15 would produce 1 char only.  Finally the third digit is discarded with `substring(1)`.

I suggest to substitute StringBuffer with StringBuilder because it is slightly more efficient and also to specify the initial buffer length:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(result.length * 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The & 0xff is there just in case byte gets promoted to something larger than 8 bits and sign-extended.

Sign-extension is a very real problem here, so the 0xff is needed for that reason at the very least.

Comment: The `0xFF` is really needed are as you conclude, I'd like to suggest you rephrase the answer, because as it stands it is slightly confusing.

Comment: "just in case byte is more than 8 bits" sounds very bad.

Comment: True. I never like to make assumptions about the underlying hardware, but in this case, the Java spec seems to say that a byte can never be more than 8 bits, so I've simplified my answer.